# How to set locale properly in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, localization, internationalization

What is the proper way of setting the locale in ActionScript, so that functions like `String.toLocaleUpperCase()` and `String.toLocaleLowerCase()` work as expected?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting line from the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#toLocaleUpperCase%28%29):

> While this method is intended to handle the conversion in a locale-specific way, the ActionScript 3.0 implementation does not produce a different result from the `toUpperCase()` method.

Following this information, here is what the documentation for `.toUpperCase()` has to say:

> This method converts all characters (not simply a-z) *for which Unicode uppercase equivalents exist*.
>   These case mappings are defined in the [Unicode Character Database specification](http://www.unicode.org/ucd/).

In summary, I don't think there is actually a way to set a locale.

Comment: Found this new class; StringTools.  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/StringTools.html. It requires Flex 4.6. There may be some hope. Giving it a shot...